# Python numpy np.argmax() using user specific range/axis

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I have an array named `fft` with the length of `length (800)` and want to get the `np.argmax(fft)` and get as expected the maximum at position `result (420)`.
The data of the fft is from -pi/2 to pi/2 (-90° to 90°). So the position of the maximum is actually at 0.078° radian. There is also an array `x_axis = np.linespace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, length)`.

I thought maybe there is a way to use the `np.argmax()` and the `x_axis` in one function or two to get the angle directly.
Would make the code clearer then using `result = np.argmax(fff) / length * np.pi - np.pi/2`.

Thanks

Comment: you can put indexes after linspace. eg: `np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, length)[0]` is the first element, so you can do `result = x_axis[np.argmax(fft)]`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks this worked. I also didn't needed to change anything in the linspace. ```np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, length)```works fine.
Thanks